# Saving a Wave Stream on local disk after Speech Synthesizing

Tags: c#, filestream, speech

How do I write the "Hello World! Speech" text as a local disk .wav file? `hellospeech.wav` remains 0Ko. Where I'm wrong?

```
     SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        MemoryStream waveStream = new MemoryStream();
        SpeechAudioFormatInfo synthFormat =  
            new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(44100, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Stereo);
        string text = "Hello World! Speech";

        synthesizer.Speak(text);
        synthesizer.SetOutputToAudioStream(waveStream, synthFormat);
        synthesizer.SetOutputToNull();
        synthesizer.Dispose();

        string path = @"E:\hellospeech.wav";
        FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write); 
        int Length = 256;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = waveStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length); 
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = waveStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        waveStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- You're not rewinding the `MemoryStream` after saving to it
- You're calling `Speak` *before* you set the output

You're also not using `using` statements - but that's not causing this issue.

I haven't used this SDK myself, but I'd expect this code to be more likely to work:

```
var waveStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    var synthFormat =  
        new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(44100, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Stereo);
    string text = "Hello World! Speech";
    // Or SetOutputToWaveStream...
    synthesizer.SetOutputToAudioStream(waveStream, synthFormat);
    synthesizer.Speak("Hello World! Speech");
}

using (var file = File.Create(path))
{
    // With WriteTo, you don't need to rewind first...
    waveStream.WriteTo(file);
}
```

Is there any reason you're writing to a memory stream first though? Why not write straight to the file, for example using `synthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile(path)`?

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work! I want to save the synthesized text as audio file. I do prefer writing to a memory so I can send it to a client via a service! or if you have a method to write it straight to the file, I will appreciate it

Comment: @Bellash: 'It doesn't work' doesn't tell me anything about what happens when you try my suggested code...

Comment: Sorry was not enough explicit! Your code creates a `0ko` file that doesn't contain the sound.

Comment: @Bellash: Hmm. In that case, I really don't know - I would definitely expect that to work. If you use `SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice`, does it speak appropriately?

Comment: If you use [`CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to rewind first. It's [`WriteTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto(v=vs.110).aspx) that writes the entire content of the [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the other stream. The sample works as intended if this change is made.

Comment: @JonSkeet it works when I use `SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice` it spells well! And Johnbot I had tried the `WriteTo` method, the file became `43ko` but It doesn't play(tried in vlc and media player)

Comment: @Bellash: Have you tried using `SetOutputToWaveStream` instead? Or frankly, `SetOutputToWaveFile` for simplicity...

Comment: `SetOutputToWaveFile` worked for me thank you! Plz edit your question in order I can accept it `using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())   {  synthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile(path); synthesizer.Speak(text); synthesizer.SetOutputToNull(); }`

Comment: @Bellash: I already edited my answer to include it as an option, but please *don't* make large edits like that to other people's answers in future. (In particular, you'd already said that you wanted to keep it in memory, so it wasn't clear that it was answering what you wanted.) Do you really need the `SetOutputToNull` call? If you're not doing anything else with the synthesizer, you shouldn't need it as far as I can tell.